# forwarding from register to authenticate not work

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have two postmapping, one is, e.g. /api/register, another is /api/authenticate, after /api/register given username and password, I want to forward the request to /api/authenticate, make it unnecessary for users input username and password again, my /api/register method like:

```
@PostMapping("/api/register")
public String register(@RequestBody xxxx) {
  ...
  return "forward:/api/authenticate";
}
```

and /api/authenticate is like:

```
@PostMapping("/api/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> authorize(@RequestBody LoginVM loginVM) {
 ....
}
```

but it does not work, I emulate with postman and get a string like: "Expected 'a' instead of 'o'", don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward / redirect only works with endpoints which support `Get` requests so `PostMapping("/api/authenticate")` would not work.

The best approach you have is to call `authorize` method directly from your code. Something like -

```
@PostMapping("/api/register")
public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> register(@RequestBody xxxx) {
    ...
    return authorize(...);
}
```